# What are the benefits of extensive reading?

Tags: reference-request, vocabulary, effectiveness, reading

What are the benefits of extensive reading? More, specifically, in what ways is extensive reading helpful for learning a target language?

Responses based on research would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on these references ([1](https://books.google.com/books?hl=en&lr=&id=_g0eSfesA-0C&oi=fnd&pg=PA225&dq=extensive%20reading&ots=Bfi6MG0_tT&sig=vPK_OIx_oke9qbP3HMSeoU_kvjg#v=onepage&q=extensive%20reading&f=false), [2](http://journals.sagepub.com/doi/abs/10.1177/003368829802900211?journalCode=rela), [3](https://search.proquest.com/openview/546d581569ad1b57279be9ca8e1e6a11/1?pq-origsite=gscholar&cbl=2031868)), there are several benefits of extensive reading:

1. Once you reach a certain level, it is thought that most of your **vocabulary acquisition** comes from reading. The context should, of course, be comprehensible.
2. Extensive reading helps with **writing and spelling**.
3. **Improved grammar**.